# Entity Framework and Azure Data Sync

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync

Has anyone used Entity Framework against a SQL Azure DB where the DB is participating in an Azure Data Sync with another SQL Azure DB?

How do code first DB migrations work with this?  Does Azure Data Sync update schema changes to the second database?

The Azure Data Sync setup adds tables and makes schema changes to the original database.  Will this cause any issues for Entity Framework?  Will I still be able to perform migrations on the original database even if the schema of the database has changed due to the Azure Data Sync setup?

Answer (score 1):

Data Sync will not automatically pick up any schema change, you have to explicitly effect the schema changes yourself and modify the sync definition as well.

the objects created by Data Sync are not in your EF model and you shouldn't be adding them either.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Will the additional schema changes caused by enabling Data Sync break EF Migrations?  Should I still be able to perform migrations against the original database even with the schema changes?  I ask because I got errors trying a migration with this environment setup.  I'm not 100% positive it wasn't something else wrong with the migration.  I'm trying to rule this out.